# What is the purpose of having a mac connected to an iPhone/iPad through bluetooth panel

Tags: bluetooth

I am not talking about handoff or things like that, these work perfectly for me among all my devices, macs, iPhones, iPads, etc.

I am talking about this: I have noticed an entry with my computer name inside the bluetooth preferences of my iPad and an entry with my iPad name inside the bluetooth settings of my mac.

Like I said, everything like handoff, clipboard between devices, etc. were working fine.

Both entries were marked NOT CONNECTED. I clicked both and all connections now say CONNECTED? What is going on here? What can I do now that I could not before?

Comment: They were not connected because bluetooth is radio.  Each device can hear the other, and probably many other devices besides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main feature is that your phone can create a Personal Hotspot via that Bluetooth connection. I.e. you can use your iPhone as an internet connection for you phone.

It is not that common to use Bluetooth for that purpose today as creating that Personal Hotspot over WiFi is both faster and more convenient given the user interface details that Apple put into that.

Comment: thanks. I think your answer approaches more the reality. Airdrop always worked for me even without this bluetooth settings off.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth can be used for many things - transfering files, creating a hotspot, connecting a device (like wireless headphones) etc.

A very Apple specific way it is used is for Airdrop. AirDrop uses Bluetooth to create a direct wifi connection between devices. If you've used AirDrop to transfer file between your Mac and iPhone / iPad, entries for the device can appear in each others Bluetooth list.

(Generally, to save battery, it is recommended to not keep Bluetooth on *always-on* mode, and use it only when needed).

Comment: This is not actually answering the question. AirDrop uses Bluetooth LE in a "connection-less" fashion - however this question was about what can be enabled by creating a Bluetooth (i.e. not LE) connection.

Comment: @jksoegaard I guess I didn't understand the question properly because of the way it was phrased.